# Magento 2: Create a Ui Component form in admin panel

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, adminform

I want to create a **Ui component form in Magento 2**. I have created a module and here are my module files.

> registration.php

```
<?php /**
* Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved. * See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register( \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Learning_HelloPage',
__DIR__
);
```

> etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved. * See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Learning_HelloPage" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved. * See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">

        <route id="demo" frontName="demo">
            <module name="Learning_HelloPage"/>
        </route>

    </router>
</config>
```

> etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/
Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="admindemo" frontName="admindemo"> 
            <module name="Learning_HelloPage" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Here are the files I have created and suggest me how can I create a Ui component form in Magento admin panel.

Comment: Have a look at this https://webkul.com/blog/create-ui-form-magento2-part-1/

Comment: just created and got 404 error on page

Comment: by the reference u sent

Comment: There might be a problem in your controller  url. Check if your controller url is correct?

Comment: yes there was a problem in controller url and i corrected it, now i got a blank page with magento admin title on it and UI form is not showing yet.

Comment: Now check your Model class. If the data is not rendered, possibly it could be an issue of model class.

Comment: can u please show me a demo here so i couldnt confuse with their code, because they has used their class and naming conventions in it. so